# How to pass auth headers in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular7

I want to access swagger API which is expecting auth credentials user/password. So I'm creating headers Object and I'm passing credentials but it still giving me `401 unauthorized error`. I'm sending my request with HTTP call as below

**Any help will on this.**

```
let headers= new HttpHeaders({
'Username':'jhon',
'Password':'Jhon123'
});

http.get(url, {headers: headers})
```

Comment: have you checked in your network (press f12 on chrome browser) if the headers are sent?

Comment: Are you sure that adding headers was the correct way to handle authentication?

Comment: @MoDGenesis yes i had checked they were not sending  i am getting 401 error with cross origin issue also here is the error reference origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.ut they were not sending.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you try set or append. You can try set like this

```
apiurl = 'yoururl';
  headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .set('Username', 'john')
  .set('Password', 'john123');

  httpOptions = {
    headers: this.headers
  };

  this.http.get(this.apiurl,this.httpOptions);
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I tried as you suggested but i am getting below error  OPTIONS https://testdemo.com/aa4j/store/features 401 (Unauthorized) Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://testdemo.aa4j/store/features' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.